# Reference next row value using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a script to fill out forms and would like to reference data from an Excel spreadsheet(one column) to fill in a reoccurring field.

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'File Path Here'

xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet1', index_col=None)

num = 1

li = [(df.iloc[0,0])]


def next_app():
    for num, elem in enumerate(li):
        thiselem = elem
        nextelem = li[(num + 1) % len(li)]
        print(nextelem)

next_app()
```

This obviously *prints* 1 value but I am not sure how to call each row value after the next whenever I need to. I am sure there are mistakes in the for loop or if I even need a for loop, but I am not sure how to rectify that.

The Excel file contains one text column named 'Application' with over 300 rows:

|Application|

|Appname1|

|Appname2|

|Appname3|

Etc.

**Problem**

I would like to reference each 'Appname' one by one when coming across a form field like the following(I am using selenium to accomplish this):

```
name = browser.find_element_by_id('slpt-createappdialog-app-name-inputEl')
name.send_keys('Appname3')
```

Except instead of inputting the text 'AppnameX' every time, I would call on the next row value. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all the apps in the list with:

```
for app in df['application']:
    name.send_keys(app)
```

or if you have separate statement creating a loop, then you can get the next app in the list each time by using a generator:

```
apps = df['application'].iteritems()

for i in range(5):
    print(next(apps)[1])
print(next(apps)[1])
print(next(apps)[1])
```

Here apps is a generator that returns an (index, item) pair, and the item part is accessed with the [1] index.

Comment: A generator, that's what I was not able to articulate. This does what I am trying to accomplish. As a follow up, if I reference the next app but I want to use that value more than once before moving onto the next item is there a way to add something on to 'stay' on a value before writing (next(apps)[1]) again?

Comment: sure, you can just write `a = (next(apps)[1])` and then use `a` until you need  the next value. If the answer helped, could you mark it as 'accepted' please?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do something like this:

```
for app in df['Application'].unique():
    # do your logic here ...
    print(app)
```